# Problem trying to select next item in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select the next element to add the class image-radio-selected with JQuery.

My html is like

```
<div id="photocall">
 @foreach ($photocalls as $photocall)
   <div class="d-inline-block mx-1">
     <div style="background-image: url('')" class="photocallThumb image-radio-selected"></div>
   </div>
 @endforeach
 <input>
</div>
```

Im trying to:

```
$( "#mybutton" ).on("click", function() {
  var selected = $('.photocallThumb.image-radio-selected'); // working
  selected.next('.photocallThumb').addClass('image-radio-selected'); // not working
});
```

After 2 hours, trying to solve, reading doc, 
I'm more confused than when I started...

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your example has no element with the ID of `mybutton` and `@foreach ($photocalls as $photocall)` isn't HTML.

Comment: `next()` finds siblings.  The inner most div has no siblings.

Comment: Define "not working".  In what way are you expecting that operation to modify that HTML?

Comment: `next()` is a sibling selector method. Even if you showed the rendered markup with a series of `mx-1` divs, `image-radio-selected` has no siblings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is you will need to get out of the `parent` div, then do a `next` for the `parent`.

```js
$( "#mybutton" ).on("click", function() {
  var selected = $('.photocallThumb.image-radio-selected');
  selected.parent(".d-inline-block").next(".d-inline-block").find('.photocallThumb').addClass('image-radio-selected'); // not working
});
```

```css
.image-radio-selected{border:1px solid #ff00aa;}
.mx-1{width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000000;}
.d-inline-block{display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="photocall">
 
   <div class="d-inline-block mx-1">
     <div style="background-image: url('')" class="photocallThumb image-radio-selected"></div>
   </div>
   
  <div class="d-inline-block mx-1">
     <div style="background-image: url('')" class="photocallThumb"></div>
   </div>
   
  <div class="d-inline-block mx-1">
     <div style="background-image: url('')" class="photocallThumb"></div>
   </div>
   
  <div class="d-inline-block mx-1">
     <div style="background-image: url('')" class="photocallThumb"></div>
   </div>
 
 <button type="button" id="mybutton">next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's `next` method selects the next *sibling* of the selected element. However, since your `photocallThumb` div is inside a `d-inline-block` div, it has no siblings. You'd have to go back up a level, then find the next `photocallThumb`, maybe something like `selected.parent().find('.photocallThumb').eq(0)`.

However, an even better pattern that will help you avoid bugs like these is called templating. Basically, on the client side, you have an html template string, and you pass it data that represent your current state. In your case, you'd pass it an array of javascript objects, each one with an image url and an `isSelected` boolean. Then, when your state changes, instead of using jquery to try to fix what's changed, you just rerender your template and replace your html element's content with the newly rendered template, and it's now magically in the correct state. This is the pattern favored by large frameworks like React and Angular.

Here's an example from lodash that renders a list of usernames:

```
// Use the "evaluate" delimiter to execute JavaScript and generate HTML.
var compiled = _.template(
    `<% _.forEach(users, function(user) { %>
        <li><%- user %></li>
     <% }); %>`);
compiled({ 'users': ['fred', 'barney'] });
// => '<li>fred</li><li>barney</li>'
```